# strange behavior of as.POSIXct

Tags: r

As working in a big data table I found NA values in a datetime column where they should not be... All these values should be "2014-03-30 02:00:00".

I made some trials:

```
> as.POSIXct("2014-03-03 02:00:00")
[1] "2014-03-03 02:00:00 CET"
> as.POSIXct("30/03/2014 2:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
[1] NA
> as.POSIXct("30/03/2014 0:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
[1] "2014-03-30 CET"
> as.POSIXct("30/03/2014 4:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
[1] "2014-03-30 04:00:00 CEST"
```

Any idea why only

```
as.POSIXct("30/03/2014 2:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

produces NA?!!

Comment: try to add the time zone. `as.POSIXct("30/03/2014 2:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT")`

Comment: OK, it's working! It's probably the date and the hour where we change hour (from wintertime to summertime in the time zone of my computer). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment, the solution here is to use

```
as.POSIXct("30/03/2014 2:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT")
```

where `GMT` can be replaced with your respective time zone.

As you already pointed out, the reason is the change from wintertime to summertime

Any time in between

```
as.POSIXct("30/03/2014 2:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

and

```
as.POSIXct("30/03/2014 2:59", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

won't work, **since this time did not exist** in your country (probably in Europe)